# How prove there exsit $f''(\xi)=\dfrac{1}{8}$

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be twice differentiable on $[-1,1]$,and such that $$\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)=-1,f(1)=f(-1)=0$$

show that: there exists $\xi\in[-1,1]$ such that 
$$f''(\xi)=\dfrac{1}{8}$$

My idea: let $\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)=f(x_0)$, then using
Taylor expansion we have
$$f(1)=f(x_0)+f'(x_{0})(1-x_{0})+\dfrac{f''(\xi_{1})}{2}(1-x_{0})^2=-1+\dfrac{f''(\xi_{1})}{2}(1-x_{0})^2\tag{1}$$
$$f(0)=f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})(-x_{0})+\dfrac{f''(\xi_{1})}{2}(-x_{0})^2=-1+\dfrac{f''(\xi_{1})}{2}(x_{0})^2\tag{2}$$
then I'm stuck. Thank you for your help

I want edit my problem,But I don't know why someone untill edit it,so I can't edit it

Comment: Some condition is missing. So far, $f\equiv 1$ satisfies the requirements, but not the conclusion.

Comment: You sure you are not missing some assumptions?any information about $f$ in $[-1,0]$?

Comment: Still, take a function $g$ satisfying the conditions, and consider $f(x) = c\cdot (g(x)+1) - 1$. For small enough positive $c$, $\lvert f''(\xi)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for any given $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Daniel Fischer pointed out in chat that for $f(x) = x^2 - 1$, it satisfies $f(1) = f(-1) = 0$ and $\min\limits_{x \in [0,1]}f(x) = f(0) = -1$, but $f''(x) = 2$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$, are you sure no other information is missing ?